# How to use optional parameters before needed ones?

Tags: java, command-line

My task for university is to write an application which can be started from the command line as the following:

```
java MyApplication [protocol:]server[:port]
```

For example:

```
java MyApplication tcp:localhost:80
```

I know that I have to design the class MyApplication as the following:

```
class MyApplication{
    public void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

then, args[0] would be the first parameter, args[1] the second parameter and args[2] the third. But how do I handle the optional argument before the obligatory one? If the optional parameter is not set, then args[0] would be the obligatory parameter, wouldn't it?

In this example it could be easy handled since I could look up whether args[0] is "tcp" or "udp" or a servername. But in another exercise of mine there are up to seven optional parameters before the obligatory one. Is there a trick how to do that?

Another thing confusing me is that we learned to separate parameters by using whitespaces. In this example it looks like it's separated by doubledots. Can I configure the args-separator somehow?

Comment: Java simply doesn't have optional parameters, as a language... it's not really clear what you're asking about. If you're talking about parsing a string which can have different sections, then it's not particularly language-specific - but no, Java's not going to parse this for you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think OP wants to implement an application that handles optional command line parameters.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi: It's not clear that's the cast, given the example - it looks like it's a matter of parsing *one* command line parameter, which has various optional sections.

Comment: What you want to do is use a `URI` here; you can detect the missing parts and replace with defaults if needed

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things the URI string is going to be passed in as a singular string argument to your application. You'll most likely need to do the parsing yourself in order to determine how to use the argument as it's passed in. Java won't add the protocol or port as separate arguments unless they're separated by a space.

As a side note, I'm a big fan of [apache commons cli](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) for making argument parsing on the command line simpler to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `args[0]` is the whole thing before the first space.

So if you do

`java MyApplication tcp:localhost:80`

then `args[0] = "tcp:localhost:80"` in your program.

And if you do

`java MyApplication tcp:localhost:80 test1 test2`

then

`args[0] = "tcp:localhost:80"`
`args[1] = "test1"`
`args[2] = "test2"`

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Now I see that there is only one argument. I think the easiest way would be to parse the string by its composition somehow?

Comment: That's right. Just take it as one string, then parse it in your Java code as you wish (and as your pre-defined URL format dictates of course).

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no spaces, they would all be read into the same string argument.  You could split the String into parts using String.split, then count the parts.  If there are one or 3 parts, then the answer is easy.  If there are two parts, then you can compare with TCP or UDP to see if the first part is the protocol or the server.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! I think this is the easiest way to split the string and compare its substrings.

Comment: You might want to consider using a different separator for part of the url.  What would happen if the server was tcp:8080?  Is that server:port, or protocol:server?  Both are valid intrepretations.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is my task to create the input as stated. I am not allowed to change the separators :( I think this results in a lot of checking.